# HMAC in Ruby from Java

Tags: java, ruby, string, cryptography, hmac

I am trying to write have the following java function in ruby:

```
public static byte[] hmac_sha1(byte[] keyBytes, byte[] text)
  throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException
{
    //        try {
    Mac hmacSha1;
    try {
      hmacSha1 = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException nsae) {
      hmacSha1 = Mac.getInstance("HMAC-SHA-1");
    }
    SecretKeySpec macKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "RAW");
    hmacSha1.init(macKey);

    System.out.println("Algorithm [" + macKey.getAlgorithm() + "] key [" + Helper.bytesToString(macKey.getEncoded()) + "]");
    System.out.println("Final text: " + Helper.bytesToString(text));

    byte[] hash =  hmacSha1.doFinal(text);

    System.out.println("Hash: " + Helper.bytesToString(hash));

    return hash;
}
```

I added the System.out.println, here is the output:

```
Algorithm [RAW] key [3132333435363738393031323334353637383930]
Final text: 0000000000000000
Hash: cc93cf18508d94934c64b65d8ba7667fb7cde4b0
```

Now in ruby I try

```
require 'openssl' 
#    
#   text: 0000000000000000
#   Key bytes: 3132333435363738393031323334353637383930 
#   Wanted hash = cc93cf18508d94934c64b65d8ba7667fb7cde4b0

digest  = OpenSSL::Digest::Digest.new('sha1')
secret = "12345678901234567890"
secret2 = "3132333435363738393031323334353637383930"
text = "0000000000000000"

puts OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(digest, secret, text)
puts OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(digest, secret, "0")
puts OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(digest, secret2, "0")
puts OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(digest, secret2, text)


puts "Wanted hash: cc93cf18508d94934c64b65d8ba7667fb7cde4b0"
```

None of the hashes match, I know it's something to do with encodings etc. How can I match the java HMAC  ?

Comment: Can you post how you derive key/text in Java?

Comment: Thanks you lead me the right direction, it's my way of encoding the resulting hash

Comment: @daniel: Do I understand right that this is solved now? If so, could you please post your solution as an answer (and later accept it)?

Comment: Yep, I'll post a solution and yes its solve but I am writing unit tests, fixing things etc, once I have everything solved I'll write the solution, probabl tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream ;
import java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException;

import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;

import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class Stack
{
    public static String hashToHexString(byte[] hash)
    {
    StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i  0) {
            hexString.append('0');
        }
        hexString.append(hexByte);
    }
        return hexString.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
      throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException

    {

        String secret = "12345678901234567890";
        byte[] keyBytes = secret.getBytes();
        String movingFact = "0";
        byte[] text = movingFact.getBytes();

        Mac hmacSha1;
        try {
          hmacSha1 = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
        } catch (Exception nsae) {
          hmacSha1 = Mac.getInstance("HMAC-SHA-1");         
        }
        SecretKeySpec macKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "RAW");
        hmacSha1.init(macKey);
        byte[] hash =  hmacSha1.doFinal(text);
        String hexString = hashToHexString(hash);
        System.out.println(hexString);
    }
}
```

Ruby code:

```
require 'openssl'

digest  = OpenSSL::Digest::Digest.new('sha1')
secret = "12345678901234567890"
movingFactor = "0"
hash = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(digest, secret, movingFactor)
puts "Hash: #{hash}"
```

output:
Java:

```
DANIELs-MacBook-Air:del dani$ javac Stack.java 
DANIELs-MacBook-Air:del dani$ java Stack
32a67f374525d32d0ce13e3db42b5b4a3f370cce
```

Ruby:

```
DANIELs-MacBook-Air:del dani$ ruby Stack.rb
Hash: 32a67f374525d32d0ce13e3db42b5b4a3f370cce
```

Done, the problem was that the java version was not translated into hexstrings properly.

Comment: I am having the same issue, but your java code has error. I'll try to figure it out though.

Comment: It would be helpful if this Java example would actually run. There are several syntax errors and a missing variable.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I ended up using an utility class from from *commons-codec-1.5.jar*, as follows:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;
// (...)
Hex.encodeHexString(rawBytes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a compiling version of the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7136019/1036299) if anybody else needs it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    String secret = "12345678901234567890";
    byte[] text = "0".getBytes();

    Mac hmacSha1 = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
    SecretKeySpec macKey = new SecretKeySpec(secret.getBytes(), "HmacSHA1");
    hmacSha1.init(macKey);

    byte[] hash = hmacSha1.doFinal(text);
    String hexString = toHexString(hash);
    System.out.println(hexString);
}

private static String toHexString(final byte[] hash) {
    Formatter formatter = new Formatter();

    for (byte b : hash) {
        formatter.format("%02x", b);
    }

    return formatter.toString();
}
```